# Auto scroll following the selected row Datatable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

This is my Datatable:

[image: Image 1]

If I press the down arrow the scroll doesn't follow the focus of the table so I have to move manually the scroll to see it. How can I do this automatically?

[image: Image 2]

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 40) { //arrow down
    if (tr.next().length) {
      table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
      tr.next().addClass('selected');
      tr = table.$('tr.selected');
    }
  }
  
  if (e.keyCode == 38) { // arrow up
    if (tr.prev().length) {
      table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
      tr.prev().addClass('selected');
      tr = table.$('tr.selected');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Create a functional example for us to look into.

Comment: Set the scrollTop of the container to the top position + height of the last cell. Exactly how you do that will depend on what your HTML looks like, so if you require a specific implementation please add a working example containing all relevant code to the question.

Comment: what "functional example" means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the scroll logic in your code to get this.

```js
 function scrollToRow(row) { 
        // Check if the row is not visible
        if (row.position().top < 0 || row.position().top > row.parent().height()) {
            // Scroll smoothly to the new row
            $(Your_dropdown_table).animate({ 
                scrollTop: row.position().top
            }, 100);
        }
    }
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: it WORKS YEEEEEEE